# Recycler view does not update the list item dynamically after adding an item from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have three fragments. One fragment shows the recycler view list items, another fragment opens up a dialog fragment which is sort of a form. It takes data and adds to the list. Now here after adding the list item the list should get updated as it's default behaviour, but it is not getting updated. But when I open activity after closing then it comes. What should be the problem can anyone tell me or can provide some sort of reference to consult. Thank you.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
List<CardListDataClass> listDataClasses = new ArrayList<>();
Fragment fragment;
FragmentTransaction ft;
List<CardListDataClass> list;
UserNameListener userNameListener;
private EditText mEditText, mEditText1, mEditText2;

// Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
public MyDialogFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_layout, container);
    mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.detailEdit);
    mEditText1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.expEdit);
    mEditText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.expExtra);

    CardView submit = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.submitDetail);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String det, exp, extra;
            det = mEditText.getText().toString();
            exp = mEditText1.getText().toString();
            extra = mEditText2.getText().toString();
            createDb createDb = new createDb(view.getContext());
            createDb.dbopen();
            createDb.createEntry(det, exp);
            createDb.close();
            listDataClasses.add(new CardListDataClass(det, exp));
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    // set this instance as callback for editor action
    mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    getDialog().setTitle("Please enter details");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        userNameListener = (UserNameListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException c) {
        Log.e("ClassCastException", "yeah");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    // Return input text to activity
    userNameListener.onFinishUserDialog(mEditText.getText().toString(), mEditText1.getText().toString());
    this.dismiss();
    return true;
}

public interface UserNameListener {
    void onFinishUserDialog(String detail, String exp);
}
```

This is the dialog fragment from where the list is to be updated in another fragment.

> Hello everyone thank u for your concern. My problem is solved now. I was referencing another new  object of list for adding the item. So the item was not being added there itself.
>
> But I have an another problem here, where I am adding the item by specifying the position item is not added dynamically, i.e.

```
list.add(position,new item(a,b))
```

Comment: can you add some code that you tried

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: [here are some of my project's file](https://github.com/Anurag690/recyclerview)

Comment: According to the docs on fragments -- they stop if not visible (hence the reason why you cant dynamic change a fragment if not visible) -- looks like you need to add the new item (On Resume)  -- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Where are you setting the RecyclerView adapter?

Comment: Please see the link I have given in the comments. There in the mainactivityfragment file